# can i use 1600 MHz and 1333 MHz RAM together?

Tags: memory

I have a Gigabyte Q2550M laptop with 2GB (1333 Mhz) and now i want to add another 4GB (1600 Mhz) ram to have a total of 6Gb RAM, but now the laptop wont boot. However, when i add the Original 2GB (1333 Mhz) to the second RAM slot, the laptop doesn't want to boot as well. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried booting just with the 4gb stick and see if it boots?

Comment: @Moab: In the proposed duplicate, the speeds are in the reverse order.  Will it still be applicable?  :-)

Comment: yes, it will always clock the ram to the lowest speed of the 2 ram modules.

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr 
Yes, you should be able to, but the settings and speed will be the lower of the 2 (still better than the 6gb stick by itself)

Not sure as of how many options you have on your laptop, but at least on a desktop motherboard you can customize the RAM options (but it does a good job selecting the options when it's only one type)

I' am running 1333 and 1600 RAM on my desktop right now, they all run at the same speed, in my case my 1333 modules dont have any problems with 1600 but it is overclocking.

It seems that your 2gb stick can't deal with 1600, so do this.
Use the 2gb stick and go to the settings in the BIOS and change the ram from auto to 1333, try the 1600 by itself and make sure its running at 1333, then plug both sticks.

Also check if there are voltage differnces, lower is better, so if one is 1.5 and the other is 1.65, it would be better to run at 1.5 but the 1.65 module might not be stable at 1.5, you could set at a medium 1.55-1.60, but I would reseach the 1.5 stick first, make sure it can handle the higher voltage.

And as far as I know it's not gonna run dualchannel anyways because of the size difference.